# Different formatting on a single cell. Python to Excel using OpenPyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, opencsv

As the title says I am trying to write into a cell in Excel using Python and the openpyxl library.

The cell in question has basically four parts all with different formatting. So:
"New Assay: Date: 01/28/2022 @ 3:00pm"

New Assay is a different font and size
01/28/2022 in Italics
3:00 pm is in bold.

I have tried to format the cell, but it formats the whole cell and not specific parts.

Comment: As far as I'm aware it is not possible to format a cell in parts like this

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything either! Thanks for answering.

Comment: No worries. Just to add onto my previous comment, that's only in openpyxl. There may be other methods to do so

Comment: You can only apply styles to cells, not parts of them.

Comment: It is achievable via VBA, so it is achievable in Python using win32.com at least.

Comment: @CharlieClark, are there any plans to implement subcell styling? Cheers

Comment: xlsxwriter supports subcell formatting. There is a PR for so called rich text formatting. It's mostly complete but has been implemented as the default and I think it should be optional.